# how to allow integer only AND not allowing more than 9 digits

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, integer, do-while

```
        System.out.println("Enter your phone number: ");
    while(in.hasNextLong()) {
        long phone = in.nextLong();
        if(in.hasNextLong()) {
            if(phone < 1000000000) {
                System.out.println("Phone number: "+phone); 
        }
    } else if(!in.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid phone number: ");
    } else if (phone < 1000000000) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid phone number: ");
    }
```

tried another way

```
        boolean valid;
    long phone;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your phone number: ");
        
        if(!in.hasNextLong()) {
            phone =in.nextLong();
            if(phone > 1000000000) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid phone number");
            in.nextLong();
            valid=false;
            }
        } 
        }while(valid=false);
    System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);
```

as you can see it doesnt work at all especially if you input a non integer and it ask for input twice im sorry its a mess

edit: ok so is there a way without using regex? my lecturer hasnt taught it yet so im not sure im allowed to use regex

Comment: Please note that your 'while (valid=false)' will never work since you're using a single '=' . With a single '=' you're assigning the value 'false' to the variabele 'valid'. What you want to do is to check the value, which is achieved by 'while (valid == false)', which can be simplified to 'while (! valid)'.

Comment: It is a misunderstanding, that a phone number is a number. It is actually a string of digits. You recognize the difference when a phone number starts with 0. It is better to represent them as a string in the program.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use regex. take a look to
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp

and try something along the lines...

```
...
final boolean isValid = inputValue.match(^[0-9]{1,9}?) // 1 to 9 digits
if (isValid) {
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: Not valid Java. --- Is that `?` supposed to be a `$`?

Comment: @Andreas, please take a moment to take a look to [regular expressions on java](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) , code above is only some pseudo code might not compile. but it will give you an idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: So I was right, being pseudo code, that is *not valid Java*. --- Although I agree that the regex itself is valid, and will give the correct result, it makes little sense. Why make the quantifier *reluctant* (`?`)? At least, if you replaced the `?` with `$`, the regex would be consistent, starting with `^` and ending with `$`, even though those are both redundant, since `match` *(should be `matches`)* is doing a full "match", not a "find".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing it this way:

```java
System.out.println("Enter your phone number: ");
int phone;
for (;;) { // forever loop
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (line.matches("[0-9]{1,9}")) {
        phone = Integer.parseInt(line);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid phone number: ");
}
System.out.println("Phone number: "+phone);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's my approach without using regex

```
System.out.println("Enter your phone number: ");
int phone;
int index = 0;
while(true) { 
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (valid(line)){
        phone = Integer.parseInt(line);
        break;
    }
System.out.println("Please enter a valid phone number: ");
}
System.out.println("Phone number: " + phone);
```

And the `valid()` method

```
boolean valid(String line){
    if(line.length() > 9) return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
       boolean isValid = false;
       for(int asciiCode = 48; asciiCode <= 57 && !isValid; asciiCode++){
       //48 is the numerical representation of the character 0
       // ...
       //57 is the numerical representation of the character 9 
       //see ASCII table
          if((int)line.charAt(i) == asciiCode){
             isValid = true;
          }
       }
       if(!isValid) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```